# c# winforms: how to catch checkbox.checked event in DGV with a bindingsource?

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview, inotifypropertychanged, bindingsource

Below is a toy program to illustrate the problem I'm having in my real application. It's a `DataGridView` with a `BindingSource` to a list of objects of a class.

The problem is: When I click a `CheckBox`, the `CheckBox` visibly changes immediately but the `invitation_property_changed()` method isn't called until I click on some other cell. I need to get the equivalent of the `Checkbox.Checked` event as soon as it occurs so I can update another control in the UI. (If I change an `OTHERS` cell, it's natural for the user to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> which triggers the `PropertyChanged` event - so this one works naturally for the user.)

Here's a screenshot, fwiw:

[image: example filled DataGridView]

Here's my toy code:

```
namespace dgv_binding_test {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {

        BindingSource bindingsource_invitations = new BindingSource();

        class an_invitation : INotifyPropertyChanged {

            static int lastID = 0;

            int _id;
            string _name;
            bool _rsvp;
            int _others;

            public int id() {
                return _id;
            }

            public string NAME {
                get { return _name; }
                set {
                    _name = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("NAME");
                }
            }

            public bool RSVP {
                get { return _rsvp; }
                set {
                    _rsvp = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("RSVP");
                }
            }

            public int OTHERS {
                get { return _others; }
                set {
                    _others = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("OTHERS");
                }
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            public an_invitation(string a_name, bool a_rsvp, int others) {
                _id = lastID++;
                _name = a_name;
                _rsvp = a_rsvp;
                _others = others;
            }

            private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "") {
                if (PropertyChanged != null) {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }
        }

        List<an_invitation> invitations = new List<an_invitation>();

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();

            an_invitation ai = new an_invitation("harry", true, 3);
            ai.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(invitation_property_changed);
            invitations.Add(ai);

            ai = new an_invitation("heidi", false, 0);
            ai.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(invitation_property_changed);
            invitations.Add(ai);

            ai = new an_invitation("henry", false, 0);
            ai.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(invitation_property_changed);
            invitations.Add(ai);

            ai = new an_invitation("hazel", true, 0);
            ai.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(invitation_property_changed);
            invitations.Add(ai);

            BindingList<an_invitation> bindingList = new BindingList<an_invitation>(invitations);
            bindingsource_invitations = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingsource_invitations;
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        }

        private void invitation_property_changed(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
            Debug.Write("change for id: " + ((an_invitation)sender).id() + "  property: " + e.PropertyName + " change: " + ((an_invitation)sender).NAME + " to: ");

            if (e.PropertyName == "NAME") {
                Debug.WriteLine(((an_invitation)sender).NAME);
            } else if (e.PropertyName == "RSVP") {
                Debug.WriteLine(((an_invitation)sender).RSVP.ToString());
            } else if (e.PropertyName == "OTHERS") {
                Debug.WriteLine(((an_invitation)sender).OTHERS.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution I've discovered for this type of situation is to handle the `DataGridView.CellContentClick` and `DataGridView.CellContentDoubleClick` events. You can keep all the current code you have.  All you'd need to add is a single handle for both of these events which ends the cell edit when it is a `CheckBox` cell.  Ending the edit will trigger the value change the same as leaving the cell currently does.

```
this.dataGridView1.CellContentClick += DataGridView1_CellContentClick;
this.dataGridView1.CellContentDoubleClick += DataGridView1_CellContentClick;

private void DataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
    {
        this.dataGridView1.EndEdit();
    }
}
```

Prematurely ending a cell's edit can be problematic - say, if it were a `TextBox` cell - due to validation. But as it's simply `True` or `False`, the point is moot in this case.